# Issues accessing Node.js command history in Emacs ansi-term

Tags: node.js, emacs, history, ansi-term

I would like to run Node (or Nodejs) interpreter 
in an Emacs *ansi-term* buffer. I found this problem: 
I can not access the common readline 
command history through ArrowUp and ArrowDown.

When I press ArrowUp and ArrowDown, instead of the expected previus commands, I get the sequences: ^[OA and ^[OB.

Have you any idea of how to fix this ?

Thank you,
Nicola Mingotti

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be in the `line` mode of `ansi-term` (although in this case I would think you would move the cursor up a line rather than displaying the escape squence...). Try using `C-c C-k` to switch to `char`. You should be able to go through command history with the arrows as usual. Use `C-c C-j` to go back to `line` mode.

Comment: Thank you for yuor answer. I tired as you suggest and indeed it improves a bit, now ArrowUp gives the previous command (with an extra prompt). But, something else is gone, in char-mode the backspace button repeats the command line instead of what expected !

I moved to to `nodejs-repl` it seems to work well even in `tramp-mode` and `isend-mode` . That is what i needed. 

bye
Nicola